# Disable " Stay on top" features on photoshop CS2

Tags: windows, photoshop

Photoshop CS2 always stay on top, even when I click another app from the windows taskbar (right of the start button).
It's completly annoying me. Always need minimized, click the other app, reclick again on photoshop, re-reminimized.

I only have 1 screen at work so I can't let photoshop on one screen and work with the other app on the other screen.

I look in all photoshop menu, find nothing

I googled the problem, and find a adobe page explain this problem is a "feature".

I only want photoshop cs2 work all other app on windows and loose focus, let new app appear on top.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem and somehow solved it. But my solution may be just as fickle as why the problem occurs in the first place. But here's what I did:

1. On the layers palette (F7) I clicked on the small arrow just below the close "X" button, on the right. Then I selected "Pallete Options"
2. Didn't change any options but just clicked OK.
3. Now the entire window remained on top, not just the palettes. So I restarted Photoshop and it seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I found that if you open up "edit > preferences > Memory & Image Cache" and set your memory usage up then it will fix it.  I am on a Windows 10.

See this post:
https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/35lmtu/photoshop_keeps_putting_itself_in_front_of_my/

Comment: This issue has been bugging me for months! I finally sorted it by boosting memory usage to 80% then restarted photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit > Preferences > File Handling > Uncheck Enable Version Cue Workgroup File Management

I literally JUST found this on accident and fixed it after having issues with all my toolbars being hidden behind stuff, and not being able to minimize without clicking on the PS window first etc. Seems to have worked!

Comment: I don't know why but this indeed fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Topmost Toggle will help you: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TopmostToggle.shtml

Works for CS2 even in Win8

Answer (score 0):

Try [Topmost Toggle](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/TopmostToggle.shtml). Works on Window 7, Window 8 and even Windows 8.1. I use it for disabling Photoshop CS2 and when Firefox bug out. Works like a charm and it's pretty easy to use:

1. Download and extract Topmost Toggle
2. Run the program - you will see that it minimize on tray
3. `Ctr + Right click` on your program and click
4. Enjoy!

Big thanks to **user2761076**

Answer (score 0):

I am having same issue with CS2 on Windows 7 64 bit. To work around, I hit tab on keyboard when photoshop window is active, that makes all pallets invisible, then I can switch to any window I need to work on.

As per this article there seem to be issue with Microsoft update https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2142314